# combine multiple lists horizontally into a single list

Tags: python, list

I have searched up and down for this in python and could not find exactly what I'm looking for.

Suppose I have the following example:

```
date_list = [Mar 27 2015, Mar 26 2015, Mar 25 2015]
num_list_1 = [22, 35, 7]
num_list_2 = [15, 12, 2]
```

How do I combine the lists so my end result is something like this:

```
combined_list = [Mar 27 2015, 22, 15
                 Mar 26 2015, 35, 12
                 Mar 25 2015, 7, 2]
```

Once I have the data in the combined_list variable, I want to be able to pass it to a for loop and iterate over each line and insert it into my SQLite db if the date does not exist or update the existing record if the date is found.

I have my separate lists and I have the database insert working. What I'm not sure about is the proper way to combine the lists. Am I looking for a pandas dataframe?  Or something else?

Any pointers to nudge me in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: Have a look at `zip`

Comment: Why is this tagged pandas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) on the three lists (I've corrected the date_list's format, the Original post doesn't have it in correct strings):

```
>>> date_list = ["Mar 27 2015", "Mar 26 2015", "Mar 25 2015"]
>>> num_list_1 = [22, 35, 7]
>>> num_list_2 = [15, 12, 2]
>>> list(zip(date_list, num_list_1, num_list_2))
[('Mar 27 2015', 22, 15), ('Mar 26 2015', 35, 12), ('Mar 25 2015', 7, 2)]
```

And as a single list using a simple list comprehension in conjunction with zip:

```
>>> [item for items in zip(date_list, num_list_1, num_list_2) for item in items]
['Mar 27 2015', 22, 15, 'Mar 26 2015', 35, 12, 'Mar 25 2015', 7, 2]
```

Note: This answer is not pandas dependent, if you are looking for a way to do this in pandas, check @EdChum's answer.

Comment: mu I tried zip and got a very odd looking response. I won't post the whole thing, but I get a list full of characters that looks like this: [(u'[', u'[', u'['), (u'\n', u'3', u'3'), (u'T', u',', u','), (u'o', u' ', u' '), (u'd', u'2', u'2'), (u'a', u'1', u'1'), (u'y', u',', u','), (u'\n', u' ', u' '), (u',', u'3', u'2'), (u' ', u'8', u'8'), (u'\n', u',', u','), (u'M', u' ', u' '), (u'a', u'2', u'2'), (u'r', u',', u','), (u' ', u' ', u' '), (u'2', u] and much more...

Comment: @ChrisC I think the input data you have is different than what I've presumed in my answer. Can you check the code, and the format for date_list etc I've used and verify if yours is the same or different?

Comment: My data comes from a page I've scraped using BeautifulSoup. I have a total of 6 lists of values that I scraped. 4 lists are integers one is decimals. The 6th is a list of dates that were also scraped from the page. That one looks like this: [Mar 27, 2015, Mar 26, 2015, Mar 25, 2015]

Comment: @ChrisC I think you will need to post the exact format and data for all the 6 lists. Maybe even ask a new question for your specific case, because I think your original question is already answered now. Also, FWIW,  `[Mar 27, 2015, Mar 26, 2015, Mar 25, 2015]` is not a valid list, you don't have the quotes anywhere, and the same is true for your original post, which I corrected in my code sample.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted this in a dataframe then you can just construct a dict with your lists as the column values:

```
In [10]:

date_list = ['Mar 27 2015', 'Mar 26 2015', 'Mar 25 2015']
num_list_1 = [22, 35, 7]
num_list_2 = [15, 12, 2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':date_list, 'num1':num_list_1, 'num2':num_list_2})
In [11]:

df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df
Out[11]:
        Date  num1  num2
0 2015-03-27    22    15
1 2015-03-26    35    12
2 2015-03-25     7     2
In [12]:

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Date    3 non-null datetime64[ns]
num1    3 non-null int64
num2    3 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2)
memory usage: 96.0 bytes
```